# How do i solve "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" error?

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob, undefined-symbol

**I used the latest version of the AdMob plugin & unity Mediation plugin.** but I still get this error, How do I solve the "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" error?. Please help me to solve this error.

Here is my pod file look like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs' source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do   pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity', '4.0.1.0'   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 9.0' end target 'Unity-iPhone' do end use_frameworks!
```

**Errors that got from Xcode:**

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_GADAdSizeLeaderboard", referenced from:
_supportedAdSizeFromRequestedSize in UnityAdapter(GADMAdapterUnityUtils.o)
"_NSValueFromGADAdSize", referenced from:
_supportedAdSizeFromRequestedSize in UnityAdapter(GADMAdapterUnityUtils.o)
"_NSStringFromGADAdSize", referenced from:
+[NSError(Unity) unsupportedBannerGADAdSize:] in UnityAdapter(NSErrorUnity.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_GADMediationAdConfiguration", referenced from:
_*OBJC*$*CATEGORY_GADMediationAdConfiguration*$_Settings in UnityAdapter(GADMediationConfigurationSettings.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_GADMediationServerConfiguration", referenced from:
_*OBJC*$*CATEGORY_GADMediationServerConfiguration*$_Settings in UnityAdapter(GADMediationConfigurationSettings.o)
"_GADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
_supportedAdSizeFromRequestedSize in UnityAdapter(GADMAdapterUnityUtils.o)
"_GADClosestValidSizeForAdSizes", referenced from:
_supportedAdSizeFromRequestedSize in UnityAdapter(GADMAdapterUnityUtils.o)
"_IsGADAdSizeValid", referenced from:
-[GADMediationAdapterUnity loadBannerForAdConfiguration:completionHandler:] in UnityAdapter(GADMediationAdapterUnity.o)
-[GADMAdapterUnity getBannerWithSize:] in UnityAdapter(GADMAdapterUnity.o)
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_GADAdReward", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in UnityAdapter(GADMUnityRewardedMediationAdapterProxy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error ScreenShot:
[image: Error ScreenShot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Heya, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

After you generate Xcode project files from unity,
pod file like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity', '3.7.1.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.8'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
  
  
end
use_frameworks!
```

You need to add these lines on aswell

so must be like these

"**target 'Unity-iPhone**' do"

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity', '3.7.1.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.8'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
  
  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationUnity', '3.7.1.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.8'
end
use_frameworks!
```